# Discord.py message spamming

Tags: discord.py

my message is spamming, I only want to send it 1 time. how to fix?

`@client.event async def on_message(message): if 'happy birthday' in message.content.lower(): await message.channel.send('Happy Birthday! ')`

Answer (score 1):

Because it's an `on_message` event and it detects also the bot's messages and bot is sending a message including **happy birthday**.

If you don't want it spamming, you can check if author is a bot account with `message.author.bot`.

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.bot:
        return
    if 'happy birthday' in message.content.lower():
        await message.channel.send('Happy Birthday! ')
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating an infinite loop, when the bot sends `”Happy Birthday!”`  `”happy birthday”`  is in the lowercase version of the message. So the bot reads `happy birthday` and sends a message, `Happy Birthday!`. Which the bot detects as a new message, the new message (when converted to lowercase) contains `happy birthday` so the bot sends a message.

There are two ways to fix this, you can change the content of the message to not contain `happy birthday`

Or you could check if the message is sent from anyone but the bot using `message.author` [message docs page](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#message)